# How get intent when device is calling?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

How can I get an Intent to my register BroadcastReceiver, when device starts call and when ends call? It doesn't matter if it is an incoming call or an outgoing call. I only need to get Intent every time when device starts its call and when ends its call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {


    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {

        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {

        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {

        }
    }
}
```

in you onCreate() add:

```
PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```